# Column not updating when tried to update a value of type varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2000. When I try to update a column of type `varchar(20)` with a text value of more than 10 characters, I get an error

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Why is it? `varchar(20)` should accept a text of up to 20 characters... why can I not update it with text with more than 10 characters?

Comment: can you post sql code with the sample text value you are trying to update?

Comment: There might be some control characters in ur string...did u check properly.. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your string variable is declared as `nvarchar(n)`, then it will take up twice as much space as a `varchar(n)`

```
10 x 2 = 20
```

So, anything greater than 10 double-byte chars will not fit into a `varchar(20)`

If you are inserting/updating into a column of type `varchar`, also declare your string variable as `varchar` with the appropriate size.

```
declare @str varchar(20)
```